# Python Pandas dataframe, how to integrate new columns into a new csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

guys, I need a bit help on Pandas and would appreciate greatly your inputs.
My original file looks like this:
[image: Original file look]

I would like to convert it by mergering some pairs of columns (generating their averages) and returns a new file looking like this:
[image: The way I want it to look like]

Also, if possible, I would also like to split the column 'RateDateTime' into two columns, one contains the date, the other contains only the time. How should I do it? I tried coding as belows but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['RateDateTime'], index_col='RateDateTime',date_parser=dateparse)

a=pd.to_numeric(df['RateAsk_open'])
b=pd.to_numeric(df['RateAsk_high'])
c=pd.to_numeric(df['RateAsk_low'])
d=pd.to_numeric(df['RateAsk_close'])
e=pd.to_numeric(df['RateBid_open'])
f=pd.to_numeric(df['RateBid_high'])
g=pd.to_numeric(df['RateBid_low'])
h=pd.to_numeric(df['RateBid_close'])

df['Open'] = (a+e) /2
df['High'] = (b+f) /2
df['Low'] = (c+g) /2
df['Close'] = (d+h) /2

grouped = df.groupby('CurrencyPair')
Open=grouped['Open']
High=grouped['High']
Low=grouped['Low']
Close=grouped['Close']

w=pd.concat([Open, High,Low,Close], axis=1, keys=['Open', 'High','Low','Close'])
w.to_csv('w.csv')
```

Python returns:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Can someone help me please? Many thanks!!!

Comment: why are you concatenating? How do you want the prices grouped (sum, mean, etc..). `grouped_df = df.groupby('CurrencyPair').agg('mean')`

Comment: @ksooklall Sorry, but could you clarify a bit more? I use concatenating because I was trying to put the new columns into a new csv file. How should I do it if I want the means of Open High Low and Close and export them all into a new csv file? And is it possible for me to split 'RateDateTime' into two columns as 'Date' and 'Time'?

Answer (score 0):

IIUYC, you don't need grouping here. You can simply update existing dataframe with new columns and specify, what columns you need to save to csv file in `to_csv` method. Here is example:

```
df['Open'] = df[['RateAsk_open', 'RateBid_open']].mean(axis=1)
df['RateDate'] = df['RateDateTime'].dt.date
df['RateTime'] = df['RateDateTime'].dt.time

df.to_csv('w.csv', columns=['CurrencyPair', 'Open', 'RateDate', 'RateTime'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just adding a note, that in order for your code to work, I have to delete "index_col='RateDateTime' " from "df = pd.read_csv()", the result gives me an additional index column, the current result works for me, but just curious if you know a way that I can remove the additional index column (number series 0 to n) upon csv.file generation? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @BernardLin set `to_csv` argument `index=False`. That specifies, that you don't want to write index to csv file.